# Custom name for params hash from Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

Ordinarily, using `form_for(@foo)` means that on the back end of the form's action, you'll have the form data in `params[:foo]`, but in my case I'd like to have a custom namespace applied to these params, i.e. `params[:bar]`, not `params[:foo]`.

I'm *not* talking about making the namespace longer by supplying the `:namespace` argument to the `form_for` method. To the contrary, my current name is overlong, and I want to shorten it. More importantly, I'm actually swapping a new model in place of an existing one, so the controller is filled with calls to `params[:quoter]`, whereas our new model supplies `params[:company_quoter_intf_quoter]`. Any ideas?

*Specs: Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3*

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
form_for(@foo, :as => :bar)
```

The documentation for this can be found at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html