# No post parameters sent when a form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers

I have a model called AlphaUser. When I submit a form to create a new alpha user, I'm told there wasn't any data in the params[:post]. How can this happen?

My code for the form:

```
<%= form_for :alpha_user,
    url: alpha_users_path,
    class: "form",
    id: "alphaTest" do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, 
            class: "form-control", placeholder: "grandma@aol.com" %>
        <%= f.text_field :producer,
          class: "hidden", value: "0" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Request Access", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class AlphaUsersController < ApplicationController  
    def create
        render text: params[:post].inspect
    end

end
```

Data is still recieved, just in this format:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blahblahblah", "alpha_user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "producer"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Request Access", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"alpha_users"}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the params[:post] to come from?  Your form is for alpha_user.  You need to reference params[:alpha_user]

Comment: I figured since the form's method was POST, it sent a POST array to the server with the data. In the Rails tutorial, it seems to work when you just use params[:post] - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra after making your change I get the Forbidden Attributes error. I added this code, but it doesn't fix it - `private
   def post_params
     params.require(:alpha_user).permit(:email, :producer)
   end`

Comment: Yeah... the rails guide is using the idea of a post (like a blog post or something) as an example.  Not the action "POST".  Kinda confusing, a poor choice on their end I think.

Comment: ah got it - still strange that my params.require(:alpha_user) doesnt fix the attributes forbidden error. (Thanks for all the help by the way!)

Comment: See my answer for a little more info.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call params for the :alpha_user... e.g. params[:alpha_user].

If you're using strong_parameters in Rails 4, this should do the trick:

```
class AlphaUsersController < ApplicationController  

  def create
    @alpha_user = AlphaUser.new(alpha_user_params)
    @alpha_user.save
  end

  private
    def alpha_user_params
      params.require(:alpha_user).permit(:email, :producer)
    end

end
```

Notice that in your create action you are no longer referencing the params directly, but the alpha_user_params method required by strong_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [Custom name for params hash from Rails form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248670/custom-name-for-params-hash-from-rails-form-for)

Also there's a reason for this naming convention. Look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) through section 7 "Understanding Parameter Naming Conventions".